# Hosting existing node.js apps on Windows Azure

Tags: node.js, azure

Is it possible to port existing node.js applications to Windows Azure platform? I currently develop on my Mac but will need to deploy the application to Windows Azure in a near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is very much possible. You may also need to consider to make changes to use Azure Blob storage where your node.js code is using local file system (if required). The deployment is very similar to any other Windows Azure App and one you have Azure SDK for node.js you can use powershell cmdlets to make your job easy.

Download Node.js SDK for Azure
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/

Here you can learn the basics to deploy node.js app to Azure:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to check a video on Channle 9.

node.js on Azure : http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Patterns-Practices-Symposium-Online/Patterns-Practices-Symposium-Online-2012/node-js-on-Azure

Answer (score 1):

Porting node.js apps to Azure is possible but not yet a yes/no answer.

You can run your Node apps in Azure but you need to look at the modules you're using to make sure you aren't depending on a tool or command or other facility that isn't yet available on Azure.  For example, are you using a database like `redis` or `couchDB` or `mysql`?  These don't exist natively in Azure so you may or may not be able to port that layer -- you'll have to check.

Since you're on a Mac, there isn't yet a native OS X deployment tool.  Microsoft and the Cloud9 folks have been showing a way for Macs to deploy from the Cloud9 IDE which works but the Mac story will most assuredly improve over time.  I work on a Mac but I keep a Windows VM open (Parallels) and if I deploy from the desktop I've been using the Powershell cmdlets in the [Windows Azure SDK for Node.js](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/) which makes things fairly turnkey from Windows.

You will want to follow a couple of repos and their contributors:   [Azure SDK for Node](http://github.com/windowsazure/azure-sdk-for-node), which allows native access to Azure Storage via `npm install azure` and [iisnode](http://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) (on Github) which is a component that assists your node app running under IIS (the Windows Web Server) on Azure.

It's been great to see the Node story on Azure evolve; it's still just a little early but they seem to be making great progress quickly.