# Is that possible to host only node js code on azure or openshift?

Tags: node.js, azure

I mean without hosting "index page" or "view", is that possible to host only node js code and database in azure or openshift. I'm server side developer, so I need to host it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the answer to your question is positive. You can start up with an empty nodejs application template provided by Azure.

Please login [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com)=>click **New** button=>select **"Web+Mobile"**=>clcik **See all**=>type *"Node JS Empty Web App"* in the search bar=>select the template to create a new Azure Web App with a default nodejs application without any views.
[image]

After creating task, you can enable the Visual Studio online extension, and you can see and modify the scripts and modules in your application. You can refer to the answer of [How to install composer on app service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035504/how-to-install-composer-on-app-service/35058312#35058312) for enabling the extension.

And login [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com), find your application in **App Services**, click **Tools** button on the header nav, click **Visual Studio Online** then click **go**, to login VSO editor.
[image]

After all, you can find your getting started application only contains one nodejs script, `server.js` with:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end('Hello, world!');

}).listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Comment: Liu, I have created the empty node js app as you said and also added composer and visual studio online extension to my app as well. But how to connect to visual studio online to modify my code? Should I install visual studio on my local machine too? Or is there any otherway to connect to the code or modify it from my local machine (like how we connect to code through git and ssh key in openshift).

Comment: No you don't need to install VS on local. Please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is absolutely possible to host node.js APIs in Azure.

The easiest way to do this is to use Azure App Service, which will automatically detect a node app and configure itself to host correctly, assuming you adhere to some conventions (your main entrypoint should be a file called app.js in the root folder, etc.):

[Node.js on Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started/)

Here's a small node API sample I created for another SO question, it has no view component and can be deployed directly to Azure App Service as-is:

[Node + Express.js API code sample](https://github.com/jplane/SO.Node.Azure.EnvVar)

There are also a variety of hosted database options for Azure, here's merely a few possible options:

[Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/?b=16.18)

[Azure DocumentDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/documentdb/)

[MySQL on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-php-create-mysql-database/)

[MongoDB on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/mongolab/mongolab/)

Any of these (and more) can be used from an Azure-hosted Node.js application.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to host NodeJS code (which, in your case, I suspect will be handling some routes like `app.get('/path', function (req, res){...});`.
For further details and ideas, please look at the discussions here on [hosting Node on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586045/hosting-existing-node-js-apps-on-windows-azure).
You can also look at the [Azure support site for NodeJS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/). I hope this points you in the right direction to find useful resources.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is most-definitely possible to host on Azure. I have done it before. You might want to use Kudu to run your command line and run commands you are most comfortable with. You can install the nodejs template from the Web App gallery and then add "scm" to your link like so https://mynodesite.scm.azure-websites.net. It will give you a commad line like the one you have on your machine and have greater flexibility.

Yours to count on