# Call a nodejs script from an asp.net Web API

Tags: asp.net, node.js, azure, asp.net-web-api, mjml

We have a REST API currently built using ASP.NET Web API and it's hosted on Azure.

One of our methods needs to compile an email template using the MJML language. Only problem is that there isn't an asp.net compiler for MJML, it's written in Node.js and none of us here know anything about node except for having used it in gulp as part of our build process.

So I guess the question is, is there an easy way (preferably on Azure) to host the node script with an endpoint that can be called from our Web API and return the compiled template.

Just to be clear, I'm not asking how to use MJML or it's compiler, just how to host a script written in Node and easy send and receive data from it. To keep this inside of Azure would be a bonus.

Many thanks.

Comment: Does [this post on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272219/is-that-possible-to-host-only-node-js-code-on-azure-or-openshift) help you?

Comment: Hmm, kind of. I guess once I've got the app set up I would need to get the mjml npm package uploaded and maybe install Express or something to create an endpoint to send the uncompiled template to? Then it's a case of asynchronously calling the mjml compiler and returning the result in the response? As you can probably tell I don't really know what I'm talking about I've just read a few node tutorials, never set up a proper server app.